# Facebook Sharing API does not get the PHP echo-ed meta data

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-graph

I have provided og:meta tags for my page which is filled in by PHP based on the GET id in the request.

The issue is, that when I check out what does the Facebook crawler see when it goes through my page, it gets empty data. All the meta tags are empty, there is no title the page is just loaded with the HTML template but no actual content in it. It sure as hell works when accessed by a normal web browser, most browsers actually.

So what could be the cause for this issue, afaik PHP is not something bots can block like they can block JS, right ?

Comment: Are you sure that the FB bot is getting the most recent version of the page?  Can it see other changes you just made on the page?   Could it be testing a page it downloaded earlier, or maybe you have a CDN or other cache that needs to be flushed?

Comment: Good thought, ill check if it sees changes and if it doesn't how can i force the api to clear the cache?